# node.js: HTTP to UDP Gateway

Tags: node.js, http, udp, gateway

I'd like to build a HTTP to UDP Gateway. Background is sending UDP Packets triggered with HTTP/AJAX. I started building a Project with Node.js.

I have a working HTTP Server and can send UDP Packages with Node.js. But I cannot send UDP Packages within the `http.request-function`. Below is an excerpt of my code:

```js
var http = require('http');
var port = 3000;

var http_server = http.createServer()

http_server.on('request', (request, response) => {
    console.log('Request: '+ request.url);
    //var message = request.url;
    var message = 'test';
    var udp_client = dgram.createSocket('udp4');
    udp_client.send(message, 0, message.length, 27994, '10.119.233.11', function(err, bytes) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('UDP message sent to ' + HOST +':'+ PORT);
        console.log(err);
    });
    response.end('done');
});
```

Why is this not working? Any workarounds? Is there in general an easier way to realise my task?

Answer (score 1):

Your particular example doesn't work: you need to define HOST, PORT, import the dgram package... Here's a version that works:

```
var http = require('http');
var dgram = require('dgram');
var udp_client = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

var server = http.createServer()
server.listen(8080)

server.on('request', (request, response) => {
    console.log('Request: '+ request.url);
    var message = 'test';
    udp_client.send(message, 0, message.length, 27994, '10.119.233.11', function(err, bytes) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
    response.end('done');
});
```